# How do I read my JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been working on it for hours, reading stackoverflow articles but I cannot figure it out. I'm trying to read information from a .json file into an array. The .json file has one key mapped to a huge array of JSON values...here is the code:

JSON file:

```
{
"SDpairs":
[{"SD Pair":"Afghanistan -
Azerbaijan","Source":"Afghanistan","Dest":"Algeria","Flow":5,"Capacity":16},
{"SD Pair":"Afghanistan - 
Azerbaijan","Source":"Afghanistan","Dest":"Australia","Flow":3,"Capacity":3},
{"SD Pair":"Afghanistan - Azerbaijan","Source":"Afghanistan","Dest":"Austria","Flow":12,"Capacity":12},
{"SD Pair":"Afghanistan - Azerbaijan","Source":"Afghanistan","Dest":"Belgium","Flow":3,"Capacity":10},
```

etc...

JavaScript method:

```
$.getJSON("SDpairs.json", function(data) {

    var str = JSON.stringify(data);
    var json = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(json);
    console.log("Type of 'json': " + typeof json);

    for (var edge in json["SDpairs"]) {
        console.log(json["SDPairs"][edge]);
        console.log("Type of 'edge': " + typeof edge);
        if (currPair == null) {
            // If it is the first JSON to be read
            currPair = [];
            currPair.push(edge);
        } else if (edge['SD Pair'] == currPair[0]['SD Pair']) {
            // If the JSON is part of the same SD pair as currPair, push into currPair
            currPair.push(edge);
        } else {
            // If it is a new SDpair as compared to currPair
            sdPairs.push(currPair);
            currPair = [];
            currPair.push(edge);
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Errors:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefinedinitData @     
 database.js:67(anonymous function) @ index.html:31
 database.js:10 Object
 database.js:11 Type of 'json': object
 database.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of     
 undefined(anonymous function) @ database.js:14f.Callbacks.o @    
 jquery.min.js:2f.Callbacks.p.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2w @ 
 jquery.min.js:4f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.c.send.d @ jquery.min.js:4
```

Update #1:

```
var sdPairs = [];

var initData = function() {
var currPair = [];

// Create and push arrays of JSONs into sdPairs. 
// Each array contains edges from the same SD Pair
$.getJSON("SDpairs.json", function(data) {

    var num = 0;
    for (var element in data["SDpairs"]) {
        var edge = data["SDpairs"][element];

        if (currPair.length == 0) {
            // If it is the first JSON to be read
            currPair.push(edge);
        } else if (edge['SD Pair'] == currPair[0]['SD Pair']) {
            // If the JSON is part of the same SD pair as currPair, push into currPair
            currPair.push(edge);
        } else {
            // If it is a new SDpair as compared to currPair
            sdPairs.push(currPair);
            currPair = [];
            currPair.push(edge);
        }

        if (num == 0) {
            console.log("Edge is " + edge);
            console.log("edge['SD Pair'] is " + edge['SD Pair']);
        }
        num++;
    }
    sdPairs.push(currPair);
});
console.log(sdPairs.length);
console.log(currPair.length);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. `$.getJSON` parses the JSON for you.

Comment: Please add the error (+ callstack) you are getting. Also could you post the entire JSON file so we are sure it's valid

Comment: You've said what you want to do, and shown us some code … but you haven't said what the problem is. What behaviour do you expect and how does that differ from what you get? How are you testing that?

Comment: And exactly **HOW** is this code not working for you?

Comment: Wow, sorry about that. I just edited the main post with the errors. Essentially, "edge" is coming up as null. "json" is logging as the actual JSON, however my calls to its child is null. The child of the JSON file is an array of JSONs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not getting the right output, for two reasons. You're only comparing keys (not their values) in your `for..in` loop. You're also losing out on the last processed set of objects when exiting the loop. You should add it at the end.

```
var sdPairs=[], currPair; // Remember to declare the variables you're using somewhere
for(var name in json["SDpairs"]) {
    var edge = json["SDpairs"][name];
    // The rest of your code
}
sdPairs.push(currPair);
console.log(sdPairs); // Do something with sdPairs now
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved that issue - there are more errors I'm getting, but that really cleared up my JSON referencing issue. Thank you again!

Comment: Hey there Pluto, I am back at it for this project and I was just wondering if you'd be willing to help with one more issue. If not, no worries at all! I understand. Anyways, I pasted my updated code in my initial post - it is under "Update #1." Both of my array length calls are returning 0. Do you have any idea why? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yeah there's a simple reason, `$.getJSON()` returns immediately before anything is downloaded (so it doesn't freeze your entire code and browser waiting on a download). What ends up happening is your array length calls are being made before your code is run. You should add a function call or more code at the end of the function inside `$.getJSON` to do stuff after the download is complete.